# System.now() gives different value than expected?

Tags: apex, datetime, date, system

For example if DateTime is :

```
DateTime dt= Datetime.newInstance(2020,07,12,18,30,0); //using System.now() for dt
DateTime.newInstanceGmt(dt.date().addDays(-5),Time.newInstance(00,00,01,00)) ;// should give 2020-07-07 00:00:01 but gives 2020-07-08 00:00:01
```

It gives 2020-07-07 00:00:01 in workbench, but not in apex.I am using System.now() for DateTime dt in apex , but even though If I print **dt** in email body,It gives me value in **gmt** , but for processing, it is considering current user's time zone.

Is this the behavior? Can anybody please confirm?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what is your locale and timezone setting on user record?

Comment: @sanketkumar The time zone is (GMT+05:30) India Standard Time (Asia/Kolkata) and Locale is English (India).

Comment: Can you clarify "DateTime dt= 2020-07-12 18:30:00".  That's not valid apex.  How is dt getting set?  Is that time GMT or local?

Comment: @JasonClark We are using System.now for setting DateTime i.e. dt, I have edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: @JasonClark  The question here is according to the documentation System.now() gives time in GMT which is what I get when I print it, but when I am processing it as in performing some actions on it like addDays(), it is giving result in accordance with current user's time zone rather than GMT timezone